# How to validate k-fold cross validation results for classifiers?

Tags: classification, t-test, cross-validation, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I've applied 6 classifiers on my data set using 5-fold CV to calculate average AUC for each model. What method do you suggest me to determine which model has the highest AUC?
I've heard of t-test and Mann Whitney test. But I don't know if using these tests are useful or should I select the best model simply by considering the model with the highest AUC by looking at them?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a two-part question: 1) how to determine which model has the highest AUC, and 2) how to select the best model.

For 1, I would say that in practice any of the methods you suggest would be fine. Chances are you're going to end up with a few models that have AUCs that are not statistically distinguishable.

That then leads to 2 - if you can't really determine with certainty which model has the best AUC, how do you choose the "best" model? In part that depends on what you are trying to do with the model. Often in the "real world", model complexity is a consideration, since you may be implementing the model in a business process or have to explain it to a client. In that case, simpler is better (it's easier to implement and explain a logistic regression than a neural net). If the costs of the outcome are really high and/or implementation costs are not a concern, then I'd choose the one with the highest AUC.

Comment: A $t$-test would be inappropriate because the data are both dependent (in 5-fold CV, the first four partitions completely determine the 5th) and not normal (AUC lies between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got this task, from a person who loves p-value. In his mind, AUC is like an effect-size, and p-value is going to show the level of significance. Yes, both are needed !

You can calculate the AUC; e.g if you use a model, that returns the output along with probability score; you can calculate AUC by varying the threshold from 0 to 1 and drawing the ROC curve; (if you need more details with code let me know).

After you have your ROC curve, you can use Wilcox to see if they are significantly different. (as @user777 mentioned, t-test is inappropriate for this case)

Eventually, keep in mind the risk of over-fitting when you are talking about the best model.

**psudocode**

```
cross.validation.table = mat.or.vec(nr = 20, nc = 5) #assume you have 100 observation - you you have randomly split them into 5 
also remember each column, indicate which observation should be tested.
for (cnt in 1:5) # start iterations for the CV
{
 test.id = cross.validation.table[,cnt] #right? you have marked who should be tested
 train.id = setdiff(c(1:100), test.id)
 fit = model(x[train.id,], y[train.id]) # train the model
 y_predicted[test.id] = predict(fit, x[test.id,], y[test.id]) # what are the predicted classes for your test samples
}
pred = prediction(y_predicted, y_true)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf ,xlab="1-specificity",ylab="sensitivity")
my.auc = performance(pred, "auc") # can comes from "ROCR"; it also returns ROC curve
...
```

Comment: I have calculated AUC using five fold CV. So, with five numbers, I should apply Mann Whitney test as I've heard it's better than t test. Am I right?

Comment: even in five fold CV you will have 1 roc curve - and 1 AUC. for each classier you will have 1 roc curve. then you can do Mann Whitney test. is that clear ?

Comment: Seem to be not clear. If I apply 5- fold cv how can I have 1 roc curve? The  classifier model of each fold as test and the others as train differ from each other. Average AUC is calculated for these five folds is computed. I don't know how can I have only one roc curve...

Comment: Do you mean I should use average AUC of each five fold cross validation and apply test on these averages?

Comment: please have a look at psudocode - I added this code, to show how you would have one ROC curve for 5-fold CV. For each model/classifier you get one ROC - AUC; let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Thanks.I understand what you mean. I have problem in implementation using `rocr`. Is `pred` a list in your code?

Comment: no - its a vector; with size $n$ where $n$ is the number of total data points.

Comment: `pred` is an array of classes but in `rocr` pred should be of type `prediction` when using `performance` function. I think `rocr` can't compute auc for k-fold cv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30668/discussion-between-user4581-and-pegah).